# Spire deployment on kubernetes and certificate retrieval

Tags: kubernetes, authentication, certificate

I am currently trying to deploy spire on my k8s cluster (3 worker nodes). My objective is to successfully deploy spire and use the certificates generated by the spire-server to encrypt the exchanges between 2 pods : a webclient and a webserver.

I followed the official tutorial https://spiffe.io/docs/latest/try/getting-started-k8s/
but have encountered some issues without being able to find the answers in the docs :

1. Although the spire-server is running fine, I am struggling to understand if the spire-agents deployed on each of the k8s nodes are working. The pods are `Running 1/1`, but I don't know how to get the SVIDs and therefore verify if everything works well (e.g if the spire-agents are registered by the server)
2. I deployed my 2 test pods (webclient and webserver) and added registration entries on the spire-server to select the tags `client` and `webserver` of my 2 pods and to register them on spire.
   From the tutorial, I know something like below should help me verify that these pods have been issued a SVID and certificate :

```
/spire-1.8.7/bin/spire-agent api fetch -socketPath /run/spire/sockets/agent.sock
```

However, the only way I managed to execute this command was by installing spire binaries on the client and webserver directly **which seems odd because I already have agents running**. In fact, I can't open a shell in the spire-agents because spire changed their images to be minimal and it doesn't include /bin/sh or anything (from what I've seen).

**Do you know a way to check for SVID issuance without installing spire on the workloads or is it the right way ?**

Following this idea, I tried to build my own spire-agent pods by adding the following commands in the yml to install spire on an alpine pod and therefore be able to connect to the spire-agent pods and debug from there :

```
kubectl -n spire exec -it spire-agent pod -- /bin/sh
wget https://github.com/spiffe/spire/releases/download/v1.8.7/spire-1.8.7-linux-amd64-musl.tar.gz
tar zvxf spire-1.8.7-linux-amd64-musl.tar.gz
cp -r spire-1.8.7/. /opt/spire/
ln -s /opt/spire/bin/spire-server /usr/bin/spire-server
ln -s /opt/spire/bin/spire-agent /usr/bin/spire-agent
```

3. Although I put the same path for the socket `agent.sock`  and mounted it to the pods, it is sometimes not found by the pods, **how should I work with this socket ?**
4. Once everything will work as expected (I hope so at least ;) ), **how should I retrieve the certificates issued by my workloads ? Are they even available from these pods so I could be able to create an https session for example ?**

Thanks for anything you can add or correct in what I've done, any help is really appreciated !